# Python not able to pickle ZabbixAPI class instance

Tags: python

I'm not able to pickle a pyzabbix.ZabbixAPI class instance with the following code:

```
from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI
from pickle import dumps

api = ZabbixAPI('http://platform.autuitive.com/monitoring/')

print dumps(api)
```

It results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zabbix_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print dumps(api)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1374, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 84, in _reduce_ex
    dict = getstate()
TypeError: 'ZabbixAPIObjectClass' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) it says:

> instances of such classes whose `__dict__` or the result of calling
>   `__getstate__()` is picklable (see section The pickle protocol for details).

And it would appear this class isn't one.  If you really need to do this, then consider writing your own pickling routines.

Comment: in the documentation I linked.